# PHP file inclusion vulnerability in grab_globals.lib.php in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, phpmyadmin

Deployed ASP.NET core 3.1 application in Google Kubernetes. Docker is built mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base.

Exposed the application with Ingress service. When doing penetration testing getting PHP file inclusion vulnerability in grab_globals.lib.php in phpMyAdmin using Metasploit.

[image]

Any suggestion or help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I have tried the below possible ways to remove this vulnerability.

- Tried to uninstall the phpMyAdmin in the docker, but phpMyAdmin is
  not found
- Tried to install and uninstall the phpMyAdmin.

Comment: which version of phpMyAdmin you're using?

Comment: @Ashok we are not using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The report screenshot you've posted talks about phpMyAdmin 2.6.4 and 2.6.4-pl1, which are both from 2005. I'm guessing that either your image is ridiculously out of date or it's a false positive. Have you investigated further what the vulnerable file is based on the report of your scanning tool? I'm looking at the base image myself and don't see any PHP files at all, so you should really investigate this further with Metasploit or your build process.